# Can second order peano arithmetic prove that first order peano arithmetic is sound?

Tags: logic, proof-theory, peano-axioms, meta-math, second-order-logic

Can second order peano arithmetic prove that first order peano arithmetic is sound?

Note that I'm not just talking about its axioms, but also its theorems.

Comment: What do you mean by your second sentence? If a set of sentences is sound, its deductive closure is also sound. (Also, how precisely are you stating "first order PA is sound" in the language of arithmetic? Or are you asking whether second-order PA proves "first order PA is $\Sigma_n$ sound" for each $n$?)

Comment: @NoahSchweber (1) does second order arithmetic prove this (2) I'm pretty sure second order arithmetic can define a truth predicate for first order arithmetic. So my question is if second order peano arithmetic proves that each theorem of first order peano arithmetic satisfies that predicate.

Comment: Ah, d'oy, (2) was silly. For (1), yes, vastly less than second-order arithmetic proves it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Second-order Peano arithmetic can create the truth predicate for sentences of first-order Peano arithmetic, and verify that every theorem of first-order PA is true under that predicate. In this way, second-order arithmetic proves the consistency of first-order PA, and proving the consistency of a theory is how we normally look at proving a theory to be sound.